# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND www.googletagmanager.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When I try my hybrid application on chrome, then I can see that Google Tag Manager is working fine but when I am trying this on the device I am getting this error on the console.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND www.googletagmanager.js?id=GTM
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: did you manage to get it working in the end?

Comment: It is likely due to the protocol. Can you provide your GTM snippet to help diagnose?